# How to call HTTP Request by using request-promise.js with many url?

Tags: javascript, request, promise

i want to ask about [request-promise.js](https://github.com/request/request-promise). I failed for solving call chain promise for many url, because i dont know how to call many urls in the same promise.

First i want to explain about my code below. In the first promise with first_link will return many urls and i will pass the urls to the second promise.

```
var req_promise = require('request-promise');
var first_link = 'http://test.com';

req_promise(first_link)
.then(function (result){
    console.log('Promise 1 finished..');
    for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
        var uri = (result[i]['uri']);
        console.log('Promise url : ' + uri + ' is being called....');

        // in this code below, it will run only the first index and the promise will finish
        // but i want to make it to run for many urls.
        return req_promise(uri);
    }
})
.then(function (result2){
    console.log('Promise 2 finished..');
    console.log(result2);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Thank you for your attention and really grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

So I manage to get the value in the seconde promise by grouping the promises in Promise.map by the url

> ```
> var req_promise = require('request-promise');
> var first_link = 'http://test.com';
>
> req_promise(first_link)
> .then(function (result){
>     // result consist of objects in array 
>     // the object have uri and title properties
>     // result.uri & result.title
>     console.log('Promise 1 finished..');
>     return result;
> })
> .then(function (result2){
>     Promise.map(data, function(d){
>         return req_promise(data.uri).then((result)=>{return result;});
>     }).then((result) => {return result});
> })
> .catch(function(err){
>     console.log(err);
> });
> ```

I hope it will hope the others if you have the same problem.

Comment: You also need to include `var Promise = require("bluebird");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all()`, `Array.prototype.map()`

```
var req_promise = require('request-promise');
var first_link = 'http://test.com';

req_promise(first_link)
.then(function (result) {
    console.log('Promise 1 finished..');
    return Promise.all(result.map(url) {
      return req_promise(url["uri"])
    }))
})
.then(function (results) {
    console.log(results)
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. I manage the get the value by using Promise.map @guest271314